# Phonegap menus and sub menus

Tags: android, blackberry, cordova

Hi does anyone have a tutorial on how to create native menus using phonegap for android and or blackberry. I just want the simple basic native menu that these mobile OS uses to add to my phonegap app

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch)

[You can see a Demo here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/)

[And the API is here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding native menus on Android is described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/EWZu1jhbVPg/XrNMA2NVrgoJ). This is like adding menu in a native app.

Alternatively, having nice menus if you use jQueryMobile is described [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html)

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic is to trap the menu key press and then show a custom DIV with the menu options, like this:

```
function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", startup, false);
}

function startup() {
    console.log("Business time...");
    menuDiv = document.querySelector("#menu");

    document.addEventListener("menubutton", doMenu, false);
}

function doMenu() {
    console.log("The menu was clicked...");
    if(menuOpen) {
        console.log("close the menu");
        menuDiv.style.display="none";
        menuOpen = false;
    } else {
        console.log("open the menu");
        menuDiv.style.display="block";
        menuOpen = true;
    }

}
```

More info on http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/5/30/Example-of-adding-menu-support-to-a-PhoneGap-Application